# How to Write scheme shell results to a file?

Tags: bash, unix, scheme, guile

I am executing some commands in guile shell.
I want the results of the command written to a file.

I tried something like this:

```
some command | nc localhost abc >> file.txt
```

But did not work for me.

Comment: What's that exact command? You may want to try with `...localhost abc &>file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `display` the results, in order to redirect them:

```
guile -c '(display (+ 1 2 3 4)) (newline)' > output
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked.

```
echo  -e "(define out (open-output-file \"/opt/ncOutput.txt\"))\n(display \"hello world\" out)\n(close-output-port out)\n" | nc localhost abc
```

[IO operations with Guile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181355/file-i-o-operations-scheme)